# Add Item Dynamically In Option

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I Have Select2 And Here is My Code:

```js
 var like = "";
        var dissLike = "";
        @foreach (var d in Model.CustomerProblems)
        {
            @:like=@d.Like;
            @:dissLike=@d.DissLike;
            @:$("#CustomerDescId").val("@d.Id");
            @:$("#CusLike").val(@d.Like);
            @:$("#CusDissLike").val(@d.DissLike);
        }
        
        Here Get Item From Model With Js 
        function formatState(state) {
                if (!state.id) {
                    return state.classList;
                }
                var $state = $(
                    '<span contenteditable="false"><img style="width: 30px; display: inline-block;" src="/images/Like.jpg" />' + like + '<img style="width: 30px; display: inline-block;" src="/images/dissLike.jpg" />' + dissLike + state.text + '</span>'
                );
                return $state;
            }
```

I need Dynamically Add Like In Model Send To Item 
Please Help Me!!

Comment: $(select2Selector).append('<option> use Than span code here </option>');

Comment: Dear Amir, Please add more detail to your question!

Comment: I have a Option that uses select 2 and in Model we are going to get the number of likes and disks and add them to a part of the option.